# Span Text Binding Error in Property Binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm Working on Xamarin Forms project using Visual Studio 2017 , I want to show few texts in side label using different styles so i used span text as  below but it gives me compile error "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Text', or mismatching type between value and property." My code is below .

```
<Label TextColor="{Binding ColorStatus}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Medium">
                            <Label.FormattedText>
                                <FormattedString>
                                    <Span Text="Thank you." FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Span Text="You have tagged-"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    <Span Text= "{Binding ActivityName}"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: Can you post the code for your view (or page) and the code of the datamodel you are trying to bind to?

Comment: <Label TextColor="{Binding ColorStatus}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding ActivityName,}"></Label> when i put like this it's workinfine so nothing wrong with ' ActivityName' binding property

Answer (score 4):

Update your `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package to the latest one. Bindable spans are available from `Xamarin.Forms` 3.1.0+ version.

More about releases and features you can find it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-3.1/3.1.0/).

Comment: thesse two spans are working without  3 rd span <Span Text="Thank you." FontAttributes="Bold"/> <Span Text="You have tagged-"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.Forms you are using?